# ReactJS debugging with WebStorm connection_err

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I am new to ReactJS and I am trying to debug it. I keep getting the following.

> [Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed.
> Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d).
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3000

This is my configuration in WebStorm:

[image]

Comment: did you start the server prior to debugging? Are there any servers listening on `127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: Which server, I guess node? How do I start the server from the configuration? I think it does it automatically since it is specified in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone, just got everything to work.
ReactJS is different from Angular.
We need to start the server manually by hand and just keep saving changes to app.js

1.Open nodeJS CMD
2. navigate to the project folder.
3. npm start

There you go!.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.3/react.html#react_running_and_debugging_debug

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure that the file you are trying to debug is a jsx file and not js file. Debugging React and normal HTML seems to be treated differently in webstrom.